# Assign array values to an item in object - Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with few items and I want to update the values of one property from array.

Object :

```
structure = [
        {
            id: 'name',
            label: 'Name',
            filterType: 'text',
            filterOn: 'contains'
        },
        {
            id: 'address',
            label: 'Address',
            filterType: 'text',
            filterOn: 'contains'
        },
        {
            id: 'phone',
            label: 'Phone',
            filterType: 'select',
            filterOn: 'contains',
            options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' },
                    { label: 'xyz', value: 'xyz' },
                    { label: 'mno', value: 'mno' }]
        }
    ];
```

if the id is phone then I want to get the values from the array and assign it to the **options** instead of hard coding it.

In this object of id phone:

```
  options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' },
                   { label: 'xyz', value: 'xyz' },
                   { label: 'mno', value: 'mno' }]
       }
   ];
```

array is coming from

```
this.props.phoneList
```

label and values will be this.props.phoneList[i].name

how to loop over this and get the latest values from the array

Comment: So, taking the array `structure` as reference, when we locate the object inside it with `id` equals to `phone`, what do you want to do? It is not clear to me. Get that value from the array and store it in a variable? or if the object `id` is phone, get the values in the `options` property of that object? Something else? Please, can you clarify this for me?

Comment: Do you want to assign `this.props.phoneList` to the object inside `structure` with `id="phone"`?

Comment: Edited, I want to apply the value of `this.props.phoneList` to the object `Options ` inside **Structure** with `id = phone`

Answer (score 0):

This should keep the order of the array intact also:

```
const newStructure = structure.map(item => {
  const isPhone = item.id === “phone”

  return {
    ...item,
    options: isPhone ? this.props.phoneList : (item.options || undefined)
  }
}
```